# Python Sprite Collision Detection

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a simple game where a player is trying to not get hit from fireballs that are being fired from all directions on the display. I have not been able to find anything online that seemed to answer my question... So what I need to do is to be able to detect if one sprite collides with a different sprite. Also if it makes a difference, both of the sprites are not rectangles or circles but png's I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is usually called pixel-perfect collision. [Here is a resource about it.](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FastPixelPerfect)

I would not use it unless I have a specific reason for using it, because it adds a serious overhead to the game loop. Instead, an approximation method with a combination of rectangles and circles may be better.

I once implemented pixel-perfect collision in a parallel-computing class using CUDA/C++ and did not suffer any performance penalties, but with Python and PyGame, the overhead will probably be very noticeable.

Comment: In that case I'll switch to the approximation method.

Answer (score 0):

[**1**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) [**2**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) [**3**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeZkAKtDIX0) You can check these tutorials, but be sure you understand Pygame basic logic first. [**This**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5F-aGDIYaM&index=1&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq) tutorial pretty awesome, you can learn basic Pygame logic with this. My advice is watch whole episodes.

Comment: @RobB. Why changing the answer?